# Stem list Tor circuit generated in file

Tags: python, tor

I am attempting to start a Tor connection using `Stem` and then list the nodes that are selected.

Using other questions and the FAQ on their website I can do one or other, but not both.

For example, I can start a Tor circuit with

```
  tor_process = stem.process.launch_tor_with_config(
    config = {
      'ControlPort': '2778',
      'Log': [
        'NOTICE stdout',
        'ERR file /tmp/tor_error_log',
      ],
    "MaxCircuitDirtiness" : str(60*60*24*30),
    "NewCircuitPeriod" : str(60*60*24*30),
    },
  )
```

And separately I can look at the circuit nodes if I start Tor separately using code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561778/how-do-i-get-the-ip-address-of-the-tor-entry-node-in-use).

But if I try to do both, such as:

```
from stem import CircStatus
from stem.control import Controller
import stem
import stem.connection
import stem.process

from stem.control import Controller

if __name__ == '__main__':
  tor_process = stem.process.launch_tor_with_config(
    config = {
      'ControlPort': '2778',
      'Log': [
        'NOTICE stdout',
        'ERR file /tmp/tor_error_log',
      ],
    "MaxCircuitDirtiness" : str(60*60*24*30),
    "NewCircuitPeriod" : str(60*60*24*30),
    },
  )

  with Controller.from_port() as controller:
    controller.authenticate()

    for circ in controller.get_circuits():
      if circ.status != CircStatus.BUILT:
        continue  # skip circuits that aren't yet usable

      entry_fingerprint = circ.path[0][0]
      entry_descriptor = controller.get_network_status(entry_fingerprint, None)

      if entry_descriptor:
        print "Circuit %s starts with %s" % (circ.id, entry_descriptor.address)
      else:
        print "Unable to determine the address belonging to circuit %s" % circ.id
  tor_process.kill()
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "circuit.py", line 22, in <module>
    with Controller.from_port() as controller:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stem/control.py", line 1024, in from_port
    control_port = stem.connection._connection_for_default_port(address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stem/connection.py", line 1058, in _connection_for_default_port
    raise exc
stem.SocketError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Which is normally the error I get when I try to do things without having separately started `tor`.

Is there a way to combine these two operations?

EDIT: There is, I forgot I set the `ControlPort` answered my question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was simple, I forgot I set the port in `config`, I set `ControlPort : 2778`, but opened `Contoller.from_port()` which uses the default port of 9051.

Using `Controller.from_port(port = 2778)` fixed the problem.